# GIT does NOT update imgs and pdfs in master

Tags: git

First of all, I have very little knowledge on git.
I use it to update my website.

I have production and beta on the server and a local repository.
When I DELETE an image or PDF in my local repository and I push the changes to beta, it is gone, but when I push them to master, it is still there. The same thing happens if I replace an image or PDF (keeping the file name but changing the content). In Beta, it updates it fine. In production it won't be updated.

I do `git ls-files filename` in master and the file is not there.

I connect to the server via FTP and the file is not there.
I go to the beta website and the file is NOT there.
I go to the production website and the file is still there.

What a mystery!

If I replace php, txt, css, etc. files everything goes as expected. There's something wrong with images and pdf, as far as I've noticed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is in you git ignore?  Check if anything being ignored

Comment: Can you tell us the commands you're using?

Comment: Thanks both for the prompt response. I need to research about git ignore and I will give you the output.

The commands I use are:
1. Make changes in local repository
2. git add --all .
3. git commit -m "message"
4. git push origin dev
5. I check that everything is as expected on the beta website
6. git checkout master
7. git merge dev
8. git commit  -m "message"
9. git push production master